# some basic unusual question on complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

Please consider the integral
\[
F(s) = \int_{c + s - i \infty}^{c + s + i\infty} f(z, s) \, dz
\]
for $s = a + bi$.

I am sure that $F(a + bi)$ is invariant when the real part of $s$ is taken out
from the path limits.

What will happen when $bi$ is taken out from the path limits?
If the integrand is independent of $s$ then $F(s)$ would not be affected.
But for the integrand dependent of $s$, I can't be pretty sure.

If we take $s$ in path limits as a sort of "shift" in path, then $F(s)$ seems
to be constant for all $s$.

Comment: What makes the integral independent of $a$? What are your assumption on $f$? If the integral exists it is independent of $b$.

Comment: My earlier comment is for the case when f is independent of s. If f depends on s then the integral can depend on both a and b.

Comment: Answer to your earlier comment. We just regard $a$ in the upper and lower limits as a constant and can use the residue theorem to shift the path by $- a$, can't we?